# Resolve FQDN but not necessarily canonical name with getaddrinfo()

Tags: c, dns, network-programming, getaddrinfo, gethostbyname

Good evening, folks.

Is it possible to use `getaddrinfo()`/`getnameinfo()` to resolve non-FQDN names to their FQDN versions, but without necessarily going all the way down to the canonical name, in a way similar to that of `gethostbyname()`?

To clarify my question, let me try to describe my use scenario, below.

1. Suppose that my company, `example.com`, has several internal departments with (semi-)autonomous DNS zone administration, each published as `deptX.example.com`, `deptY.example.com` etc.
2. Every department's computer is configured to have a DNS suffix search list in a form like

   ```
   search deptX.example.com example.com example.org
   ```
3. Department X offers a service publicly known as hosted by `host1.deptX.example.com`, but that name is actually an alias to `internal-unique-name.cloud.example.org`.
4. The internal name is (almost) never published or known by any client anywhere (unless, of course, that client cares to look at the DNS response).
5. In many (possibly most) cases, administrators configure their clients to use a shorter, partial name `host1.deptX`, relying on the DNS suffix search list to resolve the full name `host1.deptX.example.com`.  (Notice that it works everywhere, not just in Department X.)
6. Some administrator (AKA me) has to uniquely identify published services everywhere into a summarized list, classified by department, collapsing different published names referring to same host (such as the partial names and corresponding FQDN) into a single entry.

In the past, when `gethostbyname()` was the only option, I used to feed it with a partial name such as `"host1.deptX"`, and the `h_name` field in the response would give me the FQ, but not canonical, DN `"host1.deptX.example.com"`, which was very good for me.

Since `gethostbyname()` and `gethostbyaddr()` are officially obsolete for quite some time, I  thought that I should move to `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`, especially with new implementations.

However, I didn't find an equivalent to `struct hostent`'s `h_name` field.  The closest, as it seems to me, is `struct addrinfo`'s `ai_canonname`, which only gets filled when I request to resolve the canonical name, with the `AI_CANONNAME` flag.  If I do that with the scenario above, the resulting name would however be `internal-unique-name.cloud.example.org`, which is not what I want.

Am I missing anything, and maybe misusing `getaddrinfo()`?  Is there a way to have that function give me the answer that I need?

---

IMO, those partial names should have been avoided from the beginning.  OTOH, it would be impractical to try to fix them now (especially in departments other than my own), so that is not really an option.

I am certainly able to switch further from `getaddrinfo()` to libresolv's `res_query()` and its siblings, but I would like to avoid that for a number of reasons, including the ability to resolve local names (e.g. `/etc/hosts`), use local name caches (e.g. `ncsd` on UNIX) and names that are published on alternate directories, such as LDAP and NIS, but absent from the DNS (a rare, but definitely extant situation).

> **EDIT:** I tested further, and noticed that I made a mistake above.  I was under the impression that `struct hostent`'s `h_name` would always just append the short name's corresponding FQDN, but such behavior was only happening with names that were in the local database (`/etc/hosts`, which was being read before any attempt to consult DNS) and for which the FQDN was the first entry in the line.  For general, DNS-resolved names, `h_name` gets filled with the canonical name, and the non-canonical FQDN only appears in list pointed to by the `h_aliases` field.
>
> So `struct hostent`'s `h_name` is actually equivalent to `struct addrinfo`'s `ai_canonname`, with the behavior difference that `gethostbyname()` apparently always makes its version point to some data, while `getaddrinfo()` only uses `ai_canonname` if explicitly commanded by the option flag.
>
> OTOH, `struct addrinfo` doesn't have anything like a pointer to list of known aliases, that I can check against to figure out what department the host belongs to.
>
> In the end, I think I will stick to `gethostbyname()` for a little while, at least for the current tool.